# Different behavior when Rscript & rstan is run as a cron job

Tags: r, macos, cron, rscript, stan

I try to run an R script at regular intervals to update a webpage. The script runs fine when called from the terminal like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/Rscript /Users/me/path/myscript.R
```

However, if I try running it as a cron job, I get an error. I add the job to crontab like this:

```
46 10 * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript '/Users/me/path/myscript.R'  >> '/Users/me/path/mylog.log' 2>&1
```

The script does run in R, but aborts due to an error. Specifically, I fit some models using rstan, and get an initialization error. (The error only applies to some models, while others still run fine.) The initialization values are valid by definition, but do not seem to be used properly. It is like rstan is doing math differently (and wrong) when it is run through cron.

The session info from R is identical whether I run the script in the terminal or as a cron job. My question is what else might still differ depending on how the script is run. Could rstan be using a different version of C++ when run as a cron job? Are there other paths I may need to set to get this to work correctly?

Update: The script also works if I run it using `R CMD BATCH` in terminal, but not if I use `R CMD BATCH` in a cron job. Using `launchd` triggers the same issue. I also tried using `CmdStan` through `cmdstanr`, and the same same thing happens: Runs fine until added to a cron job.

Edit 2: The models I thought ran fine in cron, were not actually fine. The results were wrong, until I used the fix explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I finally managed to fix this, and I'm posting my solution here for anyone who encounters the same problem.

I ran `env` in terminal to see my current user environment. I copy-pasted the full output to the top of my crontab file. (Simply adding the PATH variable was not sufficient. I suppose it was SHELL or perhaps both PATH and SHELL that did the trick, but I haven't explored this further.)

To edit my user's crontab, I ran `crontab -e`, then pressed `i` to edit the file, pasted everything from `env` at the top of the file, stopped editing by pressing `ctrl + c`, and quit by typing `:wq` and hitting enter.

Comment: I have a complex installation of nix home-manager over Debian, and I had similar problems with R environment. I would prefer to find a more exact and elegant method to solve this, but this shotgun method also works. ;)